# How to create a bar chart with database values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I want to create a bar chart with database values.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
     ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],            // RGB value
     ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],            // English color name
     ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
     ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ], // CSS-style declaration
]);
```

Comment: Are you looking for a graph library?

Comment: yes but i need to convert the database values as bar chart

Comment: why don't you use [Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Comment: I done that before ... you need to fetch the data from database in a json format ... then var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( formatedData );

Comment: thanks florin i converted into json format